# What is the optional classes argument in Keras Applications model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

It says: "classes: optional number of classes to classify images into, only to be specified if include_top is  True, and if no weights argument is specified."

However, all the number of classes are already predetermined in the models. How can you modify the number of classes without transfer learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not true that the number of classes is completely predetermined, as the documentation states, if you specify no weights argument, its default is usually `None`, meaning that weights will be randomly initialized, so in that case Keras can adjust the number of neurons in the last layer to the number of classes that you specify.

In this case there is no transfer learning of course. Something similar can be done with custom `input_shape` values.

Comment: Aren't all models like Inception pre-trained on Imagenet? Imagenet has had a fixed 1000 classes

Comment: @Goldname Pre-training only applies if you load the weights trained on ImageNet, you might also choose not to load them and train the model from scratch.

Comment: Oh I see, then the argument is only if you decide to retrain the Inception model from scratch, right?

Comment: @Goldname Yeah, you cannot change the number of classes if you use pretrained weights, for that you would need to remove the top of the network with your own.